# What is principal ideal generated by $p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, education, maximal-and-prime-ideals, principal-ideal-domains, integral-domain

I'm studying abstract algebra, with Dummit's book.

Our professor introduced a lemma, and I'm confused with some concept.

Here is the lemma: "Let $R$ be an integral domain, and let $p$ be in $R$. Then $p$ is prime if and only if $R_p$ (principal ideal generated by $p$) is a nonzero prime ideal."

The proof of this lemma says that $p$ is prime if and only if $ab$ is divisible by $p$ then $x$ or $y$ is also divisible by $p$, and it is same with $ab$ in $R_p$ implies that $a$ or $b$ is also in $R_p$, and it is same as $R_p$ is a prime ideal.

I don't know why "$p$ is prime if and only if $ab$ is divisible by $p$ then $x$ or $y$ is also divisible by $p$, and it is same with $ab$ in $R_p$ implies $a$ or $b$ also in $R_p$."  What is the principal ideal generated by $p$?  Its mean is every ideal of $R$ is generated by $p$, right?  But how we can say that $ab$ in $R_p$ implies that $a$ or $b$ is also in $R_p$?

Comment: The principal ideal generated by an element $x$ consists of all multiples of $x$.

Comment: umm.. but I saw the definition of ideal generated by some elements is 'smallest ideal that contains those elements'. How it's mean can be a consists of all multiples?

Comment: If $x$ is in an ideal, so is all its multiples. And those already make an ideal, so it will be smallest.

Comment: Also, you should use either $a,b$ or $x,y$ but not both for the same.

Comment: oh! That's my mistake haha.. but I still don't understand why if principal ideal generated by an element x, then all elements of that principal ideal are multiple of x..

Comment: Because the set $Rx$ of multiples of $x$ is already an ideal, and any ideal that contains $x$ also contains $Rx$, hence $Rx$ is the smallest ideal containing $x$.

Comment: umm... okay. To sum up, we want to see that arbitrary element 'a' in R can represent as rx for some r in R, right? In other words, 'a' is in Rx. We show that Rx is the smallest ideal containing x, but it is related with this..? 'a' is an arbitrary element, so again, 'a' is in Rx means R in Rx, right? Then we have to see that R=Rx..? Sorry for my bad IQ.. haha

Comment: We rarely have $Rx=R$ (only if $x$ is a unit), but that's not needed at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any given element $x$ of a commutative unital ring $R$, the ideal generated by $x$ is just the set $Rx$ of its multiples. E.g. the principal ideal of $2$ in $\Bbb Z$ consists of the even numbers.

Now, $ab\in Rp$ is the same as saying $p$ divides $ab$, and thus the condition that $Rp$ is a prime ideal coincides with the condition that $p$ is a prime element.

Note also that ideals generalize the concept of 'being the multiple of *something(s)*'.

Comment: oh... It just definition.. Thank you! I still how two propositions are equivalent,
1. Ideal generated by x means smallest ideal that contains x.
2. Ideal generated by x is just the set Rx.
But, thank you!!

Comment: I answered that in the above comments, just think about it.